# Open Finder window - single instance

Tags: finder

If I click the `Show in Finder` link in Chrome's Downloads pane, every Finder pane I have suddenly comes to the foreground.

If I have several open I have to hunt around to find the Download I'm looking for.

Is there a way of disabling this action so that it **only** shows the Finder for this particular task?

This behaviour also happens elsewhere - very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

That's intended behaviour - though since Mavericks it sometimes breaks & does only focus the one window until the Finder is relaunched.

The window you requested will be the frontmost, active window.

Unlike Windows, Mac applications consider all an app's windows as part of the same process, so bringing the process to the front brings all its attendant windows.